# How to only create relevant model fields during a django test?

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, django-models

I am testing a method that requires me to create a fake record in my model. The model has over 40 fields. Is it possible to create a record with only the relevant model fields for the test so I don't have to populate the other fields? If so how would I apply it to this test case example.

models.py

```
class Contract():
  company = models.CharField(max_length=255),
  commission_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
  type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  offer = models.ForeignKey('Offer', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  notary = models.ForeignKey('Notary', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  jurisdiction = models.ForeignKey('Jurisdiction', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  active = models.BooleanField()
  ...
```

test.py

```
import pytest
from app.models import Contract

def calculate_commission(company, value):
  contract = Contract.objects.get(company='Apple')
  return value * contract.commission_rate

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_calculate_commission():
  #The only two model fields I need for the test
  Contract.objects.create(company='Apple', commission_rate=0.2)
  assert calculate_commission('Apple', 100) == 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `model_bakery` to make an object record. Just populate fields you want and leave another blank, `model_bakery` will handle it. For the Detail, you can check this out [model_bakery](https://github.com/model-bakers/model_bakery)